# Fetching Nested Data to Firestore using Classes in kotlin

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to write nested data to Firestore. But this error is coming again and again.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.util.HashMap (found in field 'prebooking')

I am sure that the error is coming because of something to do with the timestamp as earlier without the timestamp the app was running smoothly. The recycler view was populating properly.

//Prebooking Class

```
data class Prebooking(val drop_details:Timestamp, val pickup_details:Timestamp){}
```

//My model Class

```
data class AvailableVehicleModel(val vehicle_name:String="",val vehicle_number:String="", val vendor_organization:String="", val vehicle_image_url:String="", val weekday_cost:String="", val weekend_cost:String="", val prebooking: List <Prebooking> = emptyList())
```

//Code to add data to recycler view

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    fragmentView.recycler_view_available_vehicle.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(fragmentView.context)
    //create the root reference of your Firestore database
    val rootRef= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val query=rootRef.collection("available_vehicle") .orderBy("vehicle_name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AvailableVehicleModel>().setQuery(query, AvailableVehicleModel::class.java).build()
    availableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter=AvailableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter(options)
    fragmentView.recycler_view_available_vehicle.adapter=availableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter
    if (availableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter!= null) {
        availableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter!!.startListening()
    }
}

inner class VehicleViewHolder internal constructor(private val view:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    internal fun setVehicleInfo(availableVehicleModel: AvailableVehicleModel,itemId:String?){
        view.bike_name.text=availableVehicleModel.vehicle_name
        view.bike_number.text=availableVehicleModel.vehicle_number
        Glide.with(fragmentView).load(availableVehicleModel.vehicle_image_url).into(view.bike_img)
        view.bike_vendor_organization.text=availableVehicleModel.vendor_organization
        view.cost_weekday.text=availableVehicleModel.weekday_cost
        view.cost_weekend.text=availableVehicleModel.weekend_cost
        view.setOnClickListener{
            val intent=Intent(fragmentView.context, ToRentActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("item_id",itemId)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

inner class AvailableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter internal constructor(options:FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AvailableVehicleModel>): FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AvailableVehicleModel, VehicleViewHolder>(options){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VehicleViewHolder {
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.vehicle_detail_card,parent,false)
        return VehicleViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return super.getItemViewType(position)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(vehicleViewHolder: VehicleViewHolder, position: Int, availableVehicleModel: AvailableVehicleModel) {
        vehicleViewHolder.setVehicleInfo(availableVehicleModel,availableVehicleFirestoreRecyclerAdapter?.snapshots?.getSnapshot(position)?.id)
    }

    override fun onDataChanged() {
        fragmentView.recycler_view_available_vehicle.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(itemCount - 1)
        //TODO: Add a refresh sign too
    }

}
```

//

My database View:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.util.HashMap (found in field 'prebooking')

Because your `prebooking` property in your `AvailableVehicleModel` class is declared of type `List` while in the database is of type `Map`. If the `prebooking` property would have been of type `Array` in your database, there wouldn't have been a problem at all because even if the `prebooking` property is an array, when geeting, it returns an `ArrayList`, **not** an `array`.

To solve this, when trying to get the value of your `prebooking` property, get it as a `Map` and not as a `List`. Or, change the type of your `prebooking` property in your database to be of type `array` and not `object`.

Comment: Hi Tanmay! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?